# Implications of setVisible() method in Swing

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, paintcomponent

I'm writing a program that uses a few  components in a GUI. However, I don't need all of them showing at the same time. In addition, depending on the user's input, there may be times once a component is not in use anymore, that it may or may not be needed again.

So far I have simply just invoked `setVisible(false)` for each component that I do want to show on the screen. If they are needed again, i simply make them visible.

My question is this. Does setting a component's visibility to false have major implications on performance of a program (generally speaking)? Does the `paintComponent` method paint a component that is not visible and then just does not show it, or does it ignore it all together?

Also, is it better to just to remove the component from a container instead?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, a component when not visible it is not painted.  Layout managers will still need to loop through all the available components, but will normally ignore these components, but they still need to include them in there calculation loop.  Make a component visible will cause the component hierarchy to be invalidated, requiring them to be re-laid out and painted again (the same goes for making it invisible).

Comment: paint method paint all the component which is added to this container.If you can removed, then it's better to remove component from the container.

Answer (score 0):

If it is not visible it not being drawn. Lets say I made a button and then made it so it prints "Hello" when I press it. If the button `setVisible()` is false I won't be able to click on it, its not their.